# CSS - make border bottom shape like trapezoid

Tags: css

I want to create menu where I need a feature like if any user hover the menu there will be a border and the border bottom only. I want to display the bottom border like trapezoid.

> In my case i don't have a div for border, its only border-bottom.

Here is what I've tried:

```css
#myDiv{
  background: #FED;
  border-bottom: 5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
  My div, I want to make my border bottom like trapezoid.
</div>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do CSS triangles work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073484/how-do-css-triangles-work)

Comment: In my case i don't have a div for border, its only border-bottom.

Comment: use `:after` to have triangle

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by *bottom border like triangle* - Can you include an image of the output you need?

Comment: As i make a customized output from answer, I understand that my desired shape is `trapezoid and not a triangle`. Thanks @Harry

Comment: @Justinas, I change my question, Is it also the same Duplicate???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I get your correctly, you want to set the border shaped as <strike>triangle</strike> trapezoid after `#myDiv`. This is basically how you can do it with css..

```css
#myDiv:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  border-left: 1vw solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid red;
  border-right: 1vw solid transparent;
 }
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
  My div, I want to make my border bottom like triangle.
</div>
```

Comment: why he actually want this .. its looking really bad :P

Comment: Try not to use 50vw for left and right border, it adds horizontal scroll to a page.

Comment: @Era I totally agree.. Did I miss anything to understand what the OP asked?

Comment: something like this, not exactly

Comment: I can't draw my output so i can't make my expected output.

Comment: This is what i actually looking for: [https://jsfiddle.net/fgnp0thm/](https://jsfiddle.net/fgnp0thm/)

Comment: So you need a trapezoid and not a triangle :D

Comment: @RivnatNasah Aw.. you can exactly edit my style since theyre using the same method. So, its NOT a triangle !!!

Comment: Its my mistake, Thanks for quick response and help.

Comment: @RivnatNasah No worries, glad it helped.. I'll just leave my answer be like a triangle as the question's title.

Comment: @choz, can you please update your answer, I already update my question.

Answer (score 1):

```css
#myDiv {
  
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
 }
#myDiv:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 20px solid transparent;
    border-right: 20px solid transparent;
    border-top: 20px solid #f00;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -10px;
    bottom:-20px;
    display: none;
 }
 #myDiv:hover {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #f00;
 }
 #myDiv:hover:after {
  display: block;
 }
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
  My div, I want to make my border bottom like triangle.
</div>
```

```css
#myDiv {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
 }
#myDiv:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 20px solid transparent;
    border-right: 20px solid transparent;
    border-top: 20px solid #f00;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -10px;
    bottom:-20px;
    display: none;
 }
 #myDiv:hover {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #f00;
 }
 #myDiv:hover:after {
  display: block;
 }
```

Comment: Hi Sayed, Please add HTML code,<div id="myDiv">
  My div, I want to make my border bottom like triangle.
</div>, and see result on hover